# VSCode remote developement using ssh with passphrase protected ssh-key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-keys, vscode-remote

I have a remote ssh server on which I want to do remote developement.
My public key is added to the authorized keys on the server and my private key is passphrase protected.

I added the remote host as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) using `ssh user@host -i ~/.ssh/key`

But whenever I try to open a new VSCode window on the remote host it fails and I see in the log that the connection timed out, which is expected because I don't get asked for my private-key passphrase.

I read [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) post on remote development using ssh and I searched on google but couldn't find any hints to what I could do to enable/enter ssh-key passphrase while connecting to remote host.

I know I can connect to the remote using a non-passphrase-protected key but I'm not asking for that, I want to know if it's possible to connect to a remote host from VSCode using a passphrase protected key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your key is not the default one, that means you need a ~/.ssh/config entry in which you specify your SSH connection parameters:

```
Host myserver
  Hostname host
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key
```

The [Visual Studio Code Remote Development](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release) will automatically read the config file, and when you ask for opening an SSH session, you will see "myserver" entry: if you select it, the SSH session opened will use `~/.ssh/key`, the right private key.

Then, as long as your [ssh-agent is enabled](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent), and you have entered at least once your passphrase (through a manual `ssh myserver`), VSCode will use the same agent to get the passphrase when it will need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved it for me, your issue could be different.

1. In VScode, choose command: `Remote-SSH: Open SSH Configuration File...`
2. Choose the location that is offered to you (or create a config file *without extension* to desired location), for example:
   `C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.ssh\config`. Make sure you have appropriate permissions.
3. Prepare you configuration file, for example

> ```
> Host Custom_Name
>   HostName example.server.com
>   User your_user_name
>   IdentityFile C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Documents\MobaXterm\home\.ssh\id_rsa
>   (or wherever you have the private key)
> ```

4. Finally add a custom path to your configuration file. This is what I lacked for long time

> ```
> {
> // add custom configuration file path
> "remote.SSH.configFile": "C:\\Users\\[USER_NAME]\\.ssh\\config",
>
> // Other settings
>
> // omit comma after *config"* if that is your last setting
> }
> ```

Now it should ask for passphrase as opposed to password.

P.S. Here is a lot of useful information with the setup, especially with the keys that I have omitted for brevity.